# Use two drop down list selections to get a final value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two drop down lists. The first is for the employee name and the second is for any given calendar week. What I want to be able to do is select the employee then select the week and have another cell pull the hours from a second worksheet. I have the drop down lists done but I can only get a VLOOKUP to work for the week list meaning the hours won't change when selecting an employee name.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple way is to add a column on the left of your lookup table with something like:

```
=I2&"|"&J2
```

then use something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1&"|"&B1,Sheet2!$H$1:$K$4,4,0)
```

in your first sheet.

VLOOKUP is only really happy when there is a single possible answer.